# General quasilinear PDE - derivation of characteristic equation

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

A general inhomogeneous quasilinear PDE is given as 
$a(x,t,u)u_t + b(x,t,u)u_x = c(x,t,u)$.
In the derivation of the characteristic equations it says one can consider the solution to this PDE as the surface $\{(t,x,u(x,t))|(t,x)\in \mathbb{R}^2\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. Then one defines a curve $\Gamma(\eta)=(t(\eta),x(\eta),z(\eta))$ on the surface and attempts to construct another surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by $(t,x,u(x,t))$ such that $u(x,t)$ satisfies the PDE and $\Gamma\subset S$.

So far I can follow the argument. But then it just says: " To this end we consider the system of ODEs $\frac{\partial t}{\partial \xi}=a$, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi}=b$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \xi}=c$ with $t(\xi_0,\eta)= t(\eta)$, $x(\xi_0,\eta)= x(\eta)$, $z(\xi_0,\eta)= z(\eta)$"

This is too brief for me to understand. Why exactly is this the logical step to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I can answer my own question :)

It is due to the fact, that from the original equation we see that the scalar product of the vectors $(a,b,c)$ and $(u_t,u_x,-1)$ is always equal to zero and since the second vector is always normal to the surface, the first one lies in the tangent space. Hence the characteristic ODEs. (differentiate the components of the parametrization to get a tangent vector.)